# ML.net Add New Data to Exist Generated Model

Tags: ml.net

i generated a ML Model Using ML.Net V 0.7.0 last version

i need to add a new learning data to this existing Model without regenerated it with the new and old data

as i have a large data set that exceed 100 Million Record

and i need to add 100 record without reload all last data set to generate the new model

any ideas please

this is critical for me

best regards

Comment: i think we need to relearn again to enable the model to calculate based on the new data and generate the target model , we can make sub trainer but not give us the accurate result we will concern every model as a separate models and sum the result may be OK But not right in every case

Answer (score 5):

Some trainers in ML.NET support training with an initial predictor, which means you can use an existing predictor as the starting point for training with new data.

A test showing this can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/8a45f37cf87e380a93146d08acac19f215648f9a/test/Microsoft.ML.Tests/Scenarios/Api/Estimators/TrainWithInitialPredictor.cs) with the relevant code being:

```
// Train the first predictor.
var trainer = ml.BinaryClassification.Trainers.StochasticDualCoordinateAscent("Label", "Features",advancedSettings: s => s.NumThreads = 1);
var firstModel = trainer.Fit(trainData);

// Train the second predictor on the same data.
var secondTrainer = ml.BinaryClassification.Trainers.AveragedPerceptron("Label","Features");

var trainRoles = new RoleMappedData(trainData, label: "Label", feature: "Features");
var finalModel = secondTrainer.Train(new TrainContext(trainRoles, initialPredictor: firstModel.Model));
```

Comment: I think the OP is interested in adding more data to the first predictor, not creating a second type of predictor. I'm interested in this as well.

Comment: Is it as simple as train model1 and model2 and then do finalmodel=model1.append(model2)? If both models are trained the same way?

Comment: i think we need to relearn again to enable the model to calculate based on the new data and generate the target model , we can make sub trainer but not give us the accurate result we will concern every model as a separate models and sum the result may be OK But not right in every case

Comment: hi how do i create rolemapped data outside of the ml project? its a sealed class. Or how do i create a TrianContext? Thanks