# How do i add new set of images to existing ML.Net trained model ITransformer?

Tags: c#, .net, tensorflow, ml.net

I am new to Machine Learning.

I use **ML.Net Image Classification** on Windows system using **InceptionV3** and let say i already have a trained model with the **100 cats and 100 dogs** photos and saved trained model as ZIP file.

Now in future i found few more **10 cats** and i would like to add those to the existing saved trained ZIP model file instead of retraining all the old and new cats and dogs, how would i achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code which creates a Model and saves it on the last line... but now i would like to add newly found cats to the existing saved model without retraining model with the old cats & dogs photos. please help.

```
MLContext mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 1);

IEnumerable<ImageData> images = LoadImagesFromDirectory(folder: fullImagesetFolderPath, useFolderNameasLabel: true);

IDataView fullImagesDataset = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(images);
IDataView shuffledFullImagesDataset = mlContext.Data.ShuffleRows(fullImagesDataset);

var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "LabelAsKey",
                                                                        inputColumnName: "Label",
                                                                        keyOrdinality: ValueToKeyMappingEstimator.KeyOrdinality.ByValue)
                    .Append(mlContext.Model.ImageClassification("ImagePath", "LabelAsKey",
                           arch: ImageClassificationEstimator.Architecture.InceptionV3,
                           epoch: 20,
                               batchSize: 5));

  ITransformer trainedModel = pipeline.Fit(trainDataView);

  mlContext.Model.Save(trainedModel, trainDataView.Schema, outputMlNetModelFilePath);
```

Comment: I don't think the possibility exists to retrain without the older samples. unless if you somehow store the state of the training somewhere, and pick up later... I'm curious about this as well.

Comment: I don't think you can. There is no way of adding data to your trained model. There are cases where you can train a new model partly based on the older model (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318863/ml-net-add-new-data-to-exist-generated-model, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470794/ml-net-retrain-existing-model-rather-than-training-new-model?rq=1), but I don't think it's applicable to ImageClassification.